# Is vala a "pass by reference" or "pass by value"?

Tags: parameter-passing, vala

Or there exists pointers and references like ***C***?

I'm trying to get started with *vala* but is good to know if vala is *"pass by reference" or "pass by value"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you should understand that the default vala compiler `valac` compiles to C (as an itermediate language). The code is then compiled using a C compiler (usually `gcc`).

`valac -C example.vala` will compile to `example.c`

So you can inspect the produced C code yourself.

Now to the real question:

Vala supports both `call-by-value` and `call-by-reference`. It is even a bit more fine grained than that.

Let's take an example using a plain C data type (int).

Call-by-value:

```
public void my_func (int value) {
    // ...
}
```

The value will be copied into the function, no matter what you do with `value` inside `my_func` it won't affect the caller.

Call-by-reference using `ref`:

```
public void my_func (ref int value) {
    // ...
}
```

The address will be copied into the function. Everything you do with `value` inside `my_func` will be reflected on the caller side as well.

Call-by-reference using `out`:

```
public void my_func (out int value) {
    // ...
}
```

Basically the same as `ref`, but the value doesn't have to be initialized before calling `my_func`.

For `GObject` based data types (non-static classes) it gets more complicated, because you have to take memory management into account.

Since those are always managed using pointers (implictly) the `ref` and `out´ modifiers now reflect how the (implicit) pointer is passed.

It adds one more level of indirection so to speak.

`string` and array data types are also internally managed using pointers and automatic reference counting (ARC).

Though **discouraged**, Vala also does support pointers, so you can have an `int *` or `MyClass *` just like in C.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it pass by value since the underlying code is converted to C. Simple types (numeric types, booleans, enums, flags) are passed by value. Strings are passed by reference, but since they are immutable, they might as well be pass by value.

However, arrays, objects, and structs are all passed using pointers in C, so they are pass by reference. There is also the `ref` and `out` modifiers to function parameters that force those parameters to be passed by reference.